# ValueError at / The 'pic' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django

I have a simple model with pic field having null and blank

```
class PostForNewsFeed(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', null=True, blank=True, default='')



 {% if post.pic.url %}    
        <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}"
          ><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.pic.url }}" alt=""
        /></a>        
        {% endif %}
```

When I submit without a pic I am getting the pic attribute not associated with a file.

My code seems fine in the template.

Comment: You should check `if post.pic`, not `if post.pic.url`.

Comment: It still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `if post.pic`, not `if post.pic.url`:

```
{% if post.pic %}    
    <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.pic.url }}" alt=""/></a>        
{% endif %}
```

Based on the discussion, in your template you use `post.pic.url` a lot of times when you work with template tags, etc. For example:

```
{% post_to_facebook post.pic.url "Post to Facebook" %}
```

you will need to make these conditional, since you can not fetch the `.url` of a `post.pic` if that `post.pic` is non existing.

You thus need to wrap this in an `{% if … %}` condition:

```
{% if post.pic %}
    {% post_to_facebook post.pic.url "Post to Facebook" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @sly_Chandan: did you confgiure the `MEDIA_URLs`?

Comment: Yes when i submit a file it works fine. But doesnt work without a file

Comment: @sly_Chandan: what do you see if you render `{{ post.pic }}` (so you have to remove/comment all the other things regarding the `post`, since otherwise it will still raise an exception).

Comment: I just get the following error : ValueError at /
The 'pic' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: @sly_Chandan: exactly *what line*, can you copy the text on the error page on a service like pastebin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233692/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: That Worked like a charm! I did what you mentioned and it worked! Great